# Merged dev with branch but don't see merged files

Tags: git

### Problem

I had merged dev into two of my branches and the file that was suppose to be merged in is nowhere to be found.

### Commands I ran

I had to `git pull` the most recent version of dev down.

I then used `git checkout` to go to my branch.

I merged dev into that branch with `git merge dev`.

It said it was up to date, but then when I actually opened up my code the file that was supposedly merged was nowhere.

** I will say that I had committed, in both branches, when I had certain files in there that shouldn't have and deleted them, recommitted, and then one branch I actually pushed and I had to use `git rm` to delete that file and re-add it back in manually.

### Solution..?

Anyone have an idea where it went or any command I could run to get it 'back'?

My first thought was to maybe just add it in since I have a copy of it separate but I don't want to mess anything up with the flow of my branches and whatnot.

Comment: Did you delete the file in the branch you merged into?

Comment: lucky you have a copy! depending on how you removed the file and what you mean by "recommitted" it could be the file is gone for good. You can check with `git log` and move to the commits and see if the file is still somewhere. If it is not, you deleted it. For the next time. In this situation, do `git co -b work-in-progress` and then add `git add .` and commit all changes. Then move to whatever branch and do whatever needs to be done. But like so you always have a copy in source control of your latest changes...

Comment: yes. It had said it was deleted but it was still in HEAD or something like that. So I removed it from that branch and re-added it..

Comment: yeah I was worried that the fact I had a few files I technically wasn't suppose to push up in the code I deleted them and then git added and git committed again before I did my final push. 

I'm thinking really my only option now is to just delete those problematic branches and rebranch from dev

Answer (score 0):

So, the best solution, at least for my situation, is to delete the branch I am having these issues with and create a new branch off of dev. I'm lucky to have copies of the files I need for this.

I also had to go in and `git push origin --delete branch_name` because it was incorrect and had multiple problems with missing files as well as not liking existing files. (Have no idea how it got this bad lol)